# How to render LINE particles in cycles render?

Tags: particles, collision

I'm really struggling in visualizing line particles using cycles render...

I'm trying to visualize shortwave solar radiation in a city by using the LINE option (see figure) in the particle properties. I've also tried the OBJECT option, but when using this option the particles do not change direction when they collide with the mesh.

However when using the LINE option, the particles will not render in cycles.. Does anyone know a workaround to this problem?

LINE option in viewport:

[image]

LINE option in render:

[image]

Comment: Did you activate rigid body physics for the objects and for the city?

Comment: Eventually I went for the object option and added collisions to the surfaces. But thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 5):

As of Blender 2.82, Cycles only renders Objects and Collections as particles ([Blender docs link here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/particles/emitter/render.html#render-as))

However, here's a solution that might be helpful.

You can create an object shaped like a line (a long rectangle):
[image: long rectangle image]

And then use it as the Object your particle system is rendered as. Set the rotation to orient along the velocity, and make sure to check "Dynamic" in the rotation section so it updates the rotation as the particles move or bounce.
[image: particle settings]

Here's a quick view of what that generates:
[image]

Hope that helps someone Googling this in the future-

Answer (score 1):

I see what your Problem is. I tested it and it really doesn't works with objects since the Rotation Properties only allow to configure the initial orientation to be Velocity. I would suggest to use Motion Blur since it would look really like what you what to show: Particles moving at vast speeds.
In my render it actually looks like lines. One other advantage has motion blur over line rendering in Blender Internal: Bends in lines are captured correctly.

Heres my quick render:

[image]

I used Icosphere Particles and Motion Blur with a Shutter time of 2.0

Comment: And render the motion blur lines in a seperate scene as they suck up lots of samples